# Get field name within Channel form

Tags: safecracker, channel-fields

**Is there a way to show the name of the field in the front end (via Channel Form)?**

There's the Name and short_name..  I want to put the whole "question" in the field Name rather than type it in the template.

Would be nice to do something like this:

```
<label>{FIELD_NAME}</label>
<input type="text" name="{short_name}" id="{short_name}" value="{value}">
```

instead of:

```
<label>My question here with many words</label>
<input type="text" name="{short_name}" id="{short_name}" value="{value}">
```

It's because I have my form in 3 templates and it would be easier to edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the Instructions for your question text:

```
<label>{instructions:my_field_name}</label>
```

v2: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/add-ons/channel/channel_form/index.html#instructions-my-field-name

v3: https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/channel/channel_form/index.html#instructions-my-field-name

Comment: I love this idea ! ! I'll try it soon!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how many characters are in the question, you could use it as the field label when you create the custom field (or perhaps the instructions) and then output one of those in the channel form. Otherwise, a global variable might do the trick.